# Sequential Workflow: The file has been modified by SHAREPOINT\system on

Tags: 2010, workflow, development, visual-studio

I have a squential workflow that takes Account IDs as plain text from a InfoPath input and converts them into a SPUser field. I can't get the the item to update bc an exception is throw on the `Update` statement and `SystemUpdate`.

```
 CurrentItem["Stakeholders"] = usercollection; //Type: SPFieldUserValueCollection
 workflowProperties.Item.SystemUpdate(false); //Exception here         
 //workflowProperties.Item.Update();  //Exception here


//CurrentItem Definition
private SPListItem CurrentItem
{
     get
     {
         SPList list = workflowProperties.Web.Lists[workflowProperties.ListId];
         SPListItem li = list.GetItemById(workflowProperties.ItemId);
         return li;
      }
}
```

I've tried checking the item in and out. That doesn't seem to work. I've tried `CurrentItem.Item.File.Update()`. This does not throw the exception but it doesn't update the item either.

Any help would be much appreciated.

**Update**

found this in ULS:

```
Leaving Monitored Scope (EnsureListItemsData#1). Execution Time=16.7994116570681

<nativehr>0x81020015</nativehr><nativestack></nativestack>The file has been modified by SHAREPOINT\system on 03 Mar 2015 12:53:34 -0600.

Possible mismatch between the reported error with code = 0x81070901 and message: "The file has been modified by SHAREPOINT\system on 03 Mar 2015 12:49:15 -0600." and the returned error with code 0x81020037.
```

Comment: You're probably causing the workflow to fire again when you make edits to the column value. When is the workflow supposed to fire, upon creation and edits?

Comment: It's supposed to handle both events. the method that contains this code runs on both events.

Answer (score 1):

Okay I found the issue. Typical dumb mistake from staring at this too long...

```
CurrentItem["Stakeholders"] = usercollection;                
CurrentItem.Update(); //NOT workflowProperties.Item.Update();
```

Problem is now the value isn't setting but that's a separate issue. Hopefully this helps someone.

Comment: Excellent. Mark your own answer as correct. ;)

Comment: Please accept your own answer as answer, so that the question will not reflect in unanswered questions list.